# How to Extract values from nested json object and concatenate them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a javascript object in the below format. I want to combine Name and Status for each block and store in an array.

```
{
    "datatype": "local",
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "John",
            "status": "To Be Processed",
            "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-05-31 08:40:55.0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Paul",
            "status": "To Be Processed",
            "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-06-02 16:03:00.0"
        }
```

}

**Desired Output**

```
John + To Be Processed
Paul + To Be Processed
```

Please Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Your `json` is not valid. It should be

```
"data": [{...},{...}] // ] is mising

var data = {
    "datatype": "local",
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "John",
            "status": "To Be Processed",
            "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-05-31 08:40:55.0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Paul",
            "status": "To Be Processed",
            "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-06-02 16:03:00.0"
        }]
};
var len = data.data.length;
var txt = "";
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    txt += "<div>"+data.data[i].Name+" "+data.data[i].status+"</div>";
}
$("body").append(txt);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uhsws/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to create a list of processed values

```
var data = {
    "datatype": "local",
    "data": [{
        "Name": "John",
        "status": "To Be Processed",
        "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-05-31 08:40:55.0"
    }, {
        "Name": "Paul",
        "status": "To Be Processed",
        "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-06-02 16:03:00.0"
    }]
};

var result = $.map(data.data, function(obj){
    return obj.Name + ' ' + obj.status
});

console.log(result)
```