# Filter Json Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

Hello Can you help me to filter such Json Object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "statuses": [{
            "entities": {
                "urls": [],
                "user_mentions": [{
                    "screen_name": "name1"
                }]
            },
            "entities": {
                "urls": [],
                "user_mentions": [{
                    "screen_name": "name2"
                }]
            },
            "entities": {
                "urls": [],
                "user_mentions": [{
                    "screen_name": "name3"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I need to get array with values of each key screen_name.
For example: `array = ["name1","name2","name3"]`
How i can do it without frameworks with only JS?

Thanks for your help. I have updated Json to such like this:

```
var obj = {
"data": {
    "statuses": [{
        "urls": [],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "indices": [
                3,
                16
            ],
            "id_str": "626444770",
            "id": 626444770,
            "name": "katheryn",
            "screen_name": "sella_sandra"
        }, {
            "indices": [
                "***",
                "***"
            ],
            "id_str": "21447363",
            "id": 21447363,
            "name": "KATY PERRY",
            "screen_name": "katyperry"
        }, {
            "indices": [
                "***",
                "***"
            ],
            "id_str": "21447363",
            "id": 21447363,
            "name": "KATY PERRY",
            "screen_name": "floyd"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm wanna to get array of screen_names.I wrote such code.But when i use for.It doesn't work here:

`console.log (statuses[0].user_mentions[i].screen_name)`
I't silly mistake but I cannot find out how correct that. Help guys!

```
var statuses = obj.data.statuses;
for (var i=0; i<statuses.length; i++ )

 { if ( typeof statuses[0].user_mentions !== "undefined")
            {    
               for (var i=0; i<statuses.length; i++){
                  console.log (statuses[0].user_mentions[i].screen_name);
            }
        } 

    else console.log ="No senders";
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your help and edit @MikeC

Comment: `statuses` still makes no sense. `"statuses":[{"entities": {...}, "entities": {...}, "entities": {...}}]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Extract values from nested json object and concatenate them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674442/how-to-extract-values-from-nested-json-object-and-concatenate-them)

Comment: It was realy not clever.Error was in 'statuses.length'.Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect, since inside `statuses` array you cannot have another key value data.

Removing the `entities` key name assuming that it is simply an array of objects then try this

```
var obj = { "data": {
  "statuses": [
    {
      "urls": [],
      "user_mentions": [{
        "screen_name": "name1"
      }]
    },
    {  
      "urls": [],
      "user_mentions": [{
        "screen_name": "name2"
      }]
    },
    {  
      "urls": [],
      "user_mentions": [{
        "screen_name": "name3"
      }]
    }
  ]
} };

var statuses = obj.data.statuses;
var names = [];
for (var counter = 0; counter < statuses.length; counter++ )
{
   names.push( statuses[ counter ].user_mentions[0].screen_name ); 
}
console.log( names );
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax.

Comment: Array "statuses" has a lot of keys not only "entities".I wrote such way to show what i need but array can consist much more keys.

Comment: @frostrock array cannot have keys, array can only have items. Please check your array by running it on console and correct the same.

Comment: @gurvinder372 You can't start an object like you did. Run your code in the console and you'll see a syntax error. Also, you can validate JSON easily [using this tool](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: How i can request user_mentions[0]? Because when I use console.log(statuses.user_mentions[0]).I get response :Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @frostrock `statuses` is an array, so you need to try `console.log(statuses[0].user_mentions[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Given your updated data object, this returns an array of screen_names (with any duplicates removed.  If you want to keep duplicates, declare `names` as an array and push to it instead.) I used a relatively verbose coding style to make it easier to see what's going on.

```
var obj = {
    "data": {
        "statuses": [{
            "urls": [],
            "user_mentions": [{
                "indices": [3,16],
                "id_str": "626444770",
                "id": 626444770,
                "name": "katheryn",
                "screen_name": "sella_sandra"
            }, {
                "indices": ["***","***"],
                "id_str": "21447363",
                "id": 21447363,
                "name": "KATY PERRY",
                "screen_name": "katyperry"
            }, {
                "indices": ["***","***"],
                "id_str": "21447363",
                "id": 21447363,
                "name": "KATY PERRY",
                "screen_name": "floyd"
            }]
        }]
    }
};

var names = {};
for (var i=0; i<obj.data.statuses.length; i++) {
  if (obj.data.statuses[i]["user_mentions"]) {
    var mentions = obj.data.statuses[i]["user_mentions"];
    for (var j=0; j<mentions.length;j++) {
      if (mentions[j]["screen_name"]) {
        names[mentions[j]["screen_name"]] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

var arrayOfScreenNames = Object.keys(names);
console.log(arrayOfScreenNames);
```